# Typical problem on Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, derived-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this not allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674876/why-is-this-not-allowed-in-c)

**Why is this not allowed in C++...??**

```
class base
{
  private:

  public:
      void func()
         {
              cout<<"base";
         }  


};

class derived : private base
{
  private:


  public:
            void func()
         {
              cout<<"derived";
              }


};

int main()
{
base * ptr;
ptr = new derived;
((derived *)ptr)->func();
return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error

```
**61 C:\Dev-Cpp\My Projects\pointertest.cpp `base' is an inaccessible base of `derived'**
```

My question is that since func() is defined **public** in derived class and the statement 
((derived *)ptr)->func(); is trying to display the func() of **derived**..Why is there an accessible issue due to mode of inheritance..How does mode of inheritance(private) affects the call although I already have public derived func() in derived class..?

If mode of inheritance is changed to public I get my desired result..But a case where func() is private in base(so as func() of base is not inherited) and also func() is public in derived and mode of inheritance is **public** why still am I getting my desired result..Shouldn I be getting an Compile error as in the previous case ??

I am totally confused ..Please tell me how the compiler works in this case..??

Comment: also seems suspiciously like homework

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the other thread has no cast.

Comment: Hint: it's not `func` that's inaccessible. Read the error message again, and also check which line it's referring to.

Comment: @Philipp are you serious :) ? I think he just added the cast in despair hoping it will solve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't let the base pointer point to the derived object when there is private inheritance.

Public inheritance expresses an *isa* relationship. Private inheritance on the other hand expresses a *implemented in terms of* relationship

Ther compile error refers to the line:
`ptr = new derived;`

Comment: your answer might be correct, if it is all that smart guys in comments are wrong about duplicate.

Comment: What difference is there between a "has a" private inheritance and aggregation then ?

Comment: +1, as the first line is the actual problem. Now, private inheritance models *implemented in terms of*, not *has a*, that would be modeled with composition.

Comment: @Cedric With aggregation you can use several objects, like "has many", but with private inheritance you are locked to just one.

Comment: @Cedric: private inheritance allows you to override virtual functions and access protected members of the base class.

Comment: @David True I updated and changed "is a" to "implemented in terms of".

Comment: @Andrey: It is a duplicate of the other question. The answer is quite convoluted but can be described in simple terms here with something in the lines of *the private base class is not accessible and thus you cannot convert a pointer to derived to a pointer to base*.