# Why a simple mention of base pointer/reference in subsequent privately derived classes is forbidden?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

```
struct B {};
struct D : private B {
  B* fun () { return new D; }  // ok
}
struct DD : public D {
  B* foo () { return 0; } // error: ‘struct B B::B’ is inaccessible !
};
```

This error seems unreasonable to me. If we can use simple `B*` in global scope then why not in its privately derived classes? [g++ demo](http://ideone.com/ZFJdQU).

We are Not trying to convert `DD*` to `B*`, which is forbidden by the language rules ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847100/c-inheritance-inaccessible-base), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674876/why-is-this-not-allowed-in-c) are related questions).
Note that, if I change `B* foo()` to `int foo()`, things go fine.

Comment: MSVC 10.0 complains with the same error.

Comment: @Yuushi, does MSVC fixes the error with [Pubby's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13927212/514235)? Just wanted to know if this is the standard way of fixing this 'bug'.

Comment: Yes, it compiles with `::B*`.

Comment: @iammilind: It is actually the Standard's way of dealing with the error, as explained in §11.1/5 ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So apparently the compiler thinks `B` is referring to the private constructor of `B` rather than the type.

Qualifying `B` apparently fixes that error:

```
class B* foo () { return 0; }
```

or this:

```
::B* foo () { return 0; }
```

I don't know why that's happening, but maybe this will help.

---

Update: maybe it's related to 11.2.4 of standard? The only problem is that my standardese isn't good enough to fully understand it.

[image]

(sorry for the image, copy/pasting isn't working for me)

Comment: considering that 2 compilers are reporting the same error on 2 different platforms I think that is just something related to the standard or some important draft, probably about "name resolution".

Comment: @user1797612 Yeah, I agree.

Answer (score 7):

A quick look-up for *injected-class-name* in the Standard yields:

> **§11.1 [class.access.spec]**
>
> **5/** [ *Note:* In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. *—end note* ]
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> class A { };
> class B : private A { };
> class C : public B {
>     A *p; // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
>     ::A *q; // OK
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

I believe this is eerily close to your example ;)

---

Note clang 3.0's stack, which is slightly more explicit:

```
$ clang++ -fsyntax-only test.cpp
test.cpp:6:5: error: 'B' is a private member of 'B'
    B* foo () { return 0; } // error: ‘struct B B::B’ is inaccessible !
    ^
test.cpp:2:12: note: constrained by private inheritance here
struct D : private B {
           ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:1:8: note: member is declared here
struct B {};
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Here we see that `B` is accessed through `D`, instead of directly picked up in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it's not forbidden, C++ simply doesn't see the B type inside that statement or in better terms the label `B` means nothing.

Some good read about

- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376212/1797612
- [List of C++ name resolution (and overloading) rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374588/list-of-c-name-resolution-and-overloading-rules/7376212#comment8901983_7374588)